# Finding angle in the isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-transformation

There is the following triangle. I infer that the triangle is isosceles. But I cannot go further.

[image]

Comment: Are you allowed to use trigonometry?

Comment: @Bman72 I’m not but it is helpful to see the solution. If you can, I wish to learn. Thanks

Comment: @BadAtGeometry I said I infer it is isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate $B$ by 180 degrees about $N$ to get point $B'$.  Drop perpendicular from $B'$ to $BC$ meeting $BC$ extended at $E$.

[image]

By Pythgoras, $NC=AN=5$ and $NB=3\sqrt5$, hence $AB=AC=10$, $BB'=6\sqrt{5}$.  Since $AB'CB$ is fixed under rotation by 180 degrees about $N$, it is a parallelogram.  So the parallelogram law gives $2AB^2+2BC^2=AC^2+BB'^2$, i.e., $BC=2\sqrt{10}$.

Since $AB=AC=CB'$, we have $BE=\frac{3}{2}BC=3\sqrt{10}$.  So again by Pythagoras, $B'E=\sqrt{BB'^2-BE^2}=\sqrt{90}=3\sqrt{10}=BE$.  So $\triangle BEB'$ is right-angled isosceles, hence $\angle NBC=\angle B'BE=45^\circ$.

Comment: would you mind drawing it? At least the first paragraph?

Comment: Added a diagram.

Comment: The parallelogram law is the law of cosines in disguise. How did you find $BE$ from $AB=AC=CB'$?

Comment: @Paracosmiste The parallelogram law is not the law of cosines in disguise.  It can be proved with cosine law for sure, but you can also deduce it directly from Pythgoras with some algebraic manipulations.  $BE=\frac32 BC$ follows from dropping perpendicular from the apex $C$ of iscosceles triangle $AB'C$ (or equivalently $A$ to $BC$) and translating.

Answer (score 4):

$AN = 5$ (Pythagoras), so $AC = 10 = AB$, which is how you can conclude $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.

$\angle BAC = \angle MAN = \arctan\frac 34$, so $\angle CBA = \frac 12(180^{\circ} - \arctan \frac 34)$

$\angle MBN = \arctan \frac 36 = \arctan \frac 12$

$\therefore x = \frac 12(180^{\circ} - \arctan \frac 34) - \arctan \frac 12$

and you get a very nice answer in degrees.

EDIT:

The answer is $45^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{4}$, where the latter is expressed in radian measure.

This answer used trigonometry. It is being left intact because the OP found it useful. However, there was a request from the OP in comments to see if a "by-hand" calculator free solution can be obtained with my approach. Indeed it can, and here is how:

The major problems to resolve are to try to reduce the arctangent terms to single inverse trigonometric ratios.

Rearranging the above,

$\displaystyle x = 90^{\circ} - (\frac 12\arctan\frac 34 + \arctan\frac 12)$

$\displaystyle \tan x = \tan (90^{\circ} - (\frac 12\arctan\frac 34 + \arctan\frac 12))= \frac 1{\tan(\frac 12\arctan\frac 34 + \arctan\frac 12)}$

which uses the identity $\tan (90^{\circ} - \theta) = \cot \theta = \frac 1{\tan\theta}$

Let's now focus on this expression: $\frac 12\arctan\frac 34$. This can be expressed as the arctangent of simple fraction as follows:

First let's find the tangent of the above. Note that $\tan \frac 12\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$, which can be looked up in a reference, or may be proved fairly easily by considering the individual half-angle identities for sine and cosine and dividing them.

Also note that if $\theta = \arctan \frac34$ then $\sin\theta = \frac 35$ and $\cos\theta = \frac 45$, which is quite trivial to show by considering the $3-4-5$ special right triangle.

Putting those together:

$\displaystyle \tan \frac 12\arctan\frac 34 = \frac{\sin (\arctan\frac 34)}{1+ \cos (\arctan\frac 34)} = \frac{\frac 35}{1+\frac 45} = \frac 13$

Therefore $\frac 12\arctan\frac 34 = \arctan \frac 13$

So $\displaystyle \tan x =\frac 1{\tan(\frac 12\arctan\frac 34 + \arctan\frac 12)} = \frac 1{\tan(\arctan \frac 13 + \arctan \frac 12)}$

Apply the angle addition formula for tangent to get:

$\displaystyle \tan x = \frac 1{\frac{\tan(\arctan \frac 13) + \tan(\arctan \frac 12)}{1- \tan(\arctan \frac 13)\tan(\arctan \frac 12)}} = \frac 1{\frac{\frac 13+\frac 12}{1- \frac 13\cdot \frac 12}}  = \frac 11 = 1$

and the only acute angle solution for $\tan x = 1$ is $x = 45^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

I hope this is a more "satisfying" solution for the OP. As I said, it's possible to do it without a calculator, just harder.

Comment: Nice solution! However he is not allowed to use trigonometry

Comment: @Bman72 but it helps to see what’s going on. The answer is really helpful.

Comment: Deepak do we need to use calculator to get the answer by your solution?

Comment: @concurrencyboy A calculator is the simplest approach. It might be possible to simplify using trigonometric identities but it's definitely more difficult.

Comment: @concurrencyboy I have updated my solution to show you a calculator-free way to proceed.

Comment: @Deepak Your solution is correct but the OP doesn't want to use trigonometry. I suggest to add a "geometry-without-trigonometry" tag so users know how should they answer. If you agree please support this suggestion [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30405/81595).

Answer (score 0):

## Without trigonometry

Let $D$ be the symmetric of $C$ with respect to $A$, $H$ and $K$ the orthogonal projections of $A$ and $C$ on $BC$ and $AB$.

$BCD$ is a right triangle. By the midpoint theorem, $CK=2MN=6$ and $MN=MA=4$ so $BK=2$. By Pythagoras theorem, $BC=\sqrt{BK^2+CK^2}=2\sqrt{10}$ and $AH=\sqrt{AB^2-BH^2}=3\sqrt{10}$.

$\dfrac{NC}{ND}=\dfrac{5}{15}=\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $\dfrac{BC}{BD}=\dfrac{BC}{2AH}=\dfrac{1}{3}$ so, by [the angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), $BN$ is the interior bisector of the right angle $CBD$. Thus $x=45^\circ$.

[image]

## With trigonometry

$\cos BAC=4/5$ and $BC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2AB\cdot AC\cdot\cos BAC=40$ by the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

$NC^2=NB^2+BC^2-2NB\cdot BC\cdot\cos x$ gives $x=45^{\circ}$